# How to Allow Calls on Button Click in Android Web View App?

Tags: java, android

I am building an Android app and I am newbie.
I am not able to make calls by clicking a button inside android webview app

[image]

Here is my code:

Mainactivity

```
package pk.gogobazar.gogobazarapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    WebView webView;
    private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
    public ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessage;
    public static final int REQUEST_SELECT_FILE = 100;
    private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

    public String url ="https://gogobazar.pk/";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new xWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {

            // For 3.0+ Devices (Start)
            // onActivityResult attached before constructor
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }


            // For Lollipop 5.0+ Devices
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView mWebView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
            {
                if (uploadMessage != null) {
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(null);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

                uploadMessage = filePathCallback;

                Intent intent = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    intent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                }
                try
                {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_FILE);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
                {
                    uploadMessage = null;
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            //For Android 4.1 only
            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "File Browser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }

            protected void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg)
            {
                mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
            }
        });






    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_SELECT_FILE)
            {
                if (uploadMessage == null)
                    return;
                uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent));
                uploadMessage = null;
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE)
        {
            if (null == mUploadMessage)
                return;
            // Use MainActivity.RESULT_OK if you're implementing WebView inside Fragment
            // Use RESULT_OK only if you're implementing WebView inside an Activity
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != MainActivity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mUploadMessage = null;
        }


    }


    private class xWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }




}
```

Android Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pk.gogobazar.gogobazarapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am new and still learning basics. Please help me to allow the phone calls in webview on this activity. So when someone clicks on phone number it should call, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is How it works for me:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TEL_PREFIX = "tel:";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        wv.loadUrl("https://google.pk");
        WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView wv, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith(TEL_PREFIX)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: in android manifest:

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to bind your javascript code to your android code, [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) demonstrates how to do that. Then in your javascript, you could add a listener to your button that invokes a Java method.

Second, you need to integrate a calling solution into your app [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom#integrateCalling) explains what options you have and how you can implement them.

Once you implemented the calling solution, you could simply make a call from the Java method that you intend to invoke from your javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply as i am still new to android and have no knowlege of coding at all... could you please tell me how to do it

Comment: I already explained how to approach the problem, now its up to you on how to implement it. The first guide already shows how to implement the binding between JS and Java. As for the calling API, I'm not familiar with it so you just have to google for examples.